# Shaderを使って配管を流れる流体をアニメーションで表現したい

Tags: unity3d, shader, shader-graph

配管の表面を流体が流れ、かつ流れている方向が一目でわかるようなアニメーションを作りたいと思っています。
UnityのShaderという機能を使えばできそうなのですが、中身が難しく先へ進めません。
Shaderで上記の表現を実現する方法、もしくは別の手段などがあれば教えて頂きたいのですが・・・。

Comment: 求めるブツの最終形態は何？　動画ファイル・表示するだけのアプリ・Web Page 上でアニメーションっぽく見えればよい・などなど。オイラなら流れ方向に矢印でも表示して点滅させる gif ファイル作って終わりにします。（表現が悪い。配管の表面＝管壁における流体の流速は０っス。中央部ならいざしらず）

Comment: イメージとしては、パイプの表面上を縞々模様が流れ方向に沿って動くようなアニメーションを表示させたいです。